# Python 2.7: adding a new collection item to the top of HTML table (not the bottom)

Tags: jquery, django, python-2.7, html-table

I have the following table:

```
        <table id='digital-item-table' style='width:100%;margin-top:10px;'>
            <tr>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>Code</th>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>Name</th>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>Date Created</th>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>File Size (bytes)</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>            

        {% if collection_items|length > 0 %}    
            {% for item in collection_items %}
                {% autoescape off %}
                    <tr class="refreshed-row">
                        <td>{{ item.DigitalItem.LicenseCode }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.DigitalItem.Name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.DigitalItem.DateTimeCreated }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.DigitalItem.FileSizeBytes }}</td>
                        <td><a class='standard-link' href='{{dfs_base_url}}{{ item.DigitalItem.DownloadLink }}'>download</a></td>
                        <td><a class="deleteLink" href="#" >delete</a></td>
                    </tr>  
                {% endautoescape %} 
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan=4>There are no items, just yet.</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        </table>
```

This is for a file upload/file-drag-and-drop setup.

1) user browses for a file/drags and drops a file

2) the file is uploaded-you see the details of the file in a div

3) when you REFRESH the page, the file details (ie `item.DigitalItem.DateTimeCreated`) are added to the table with id of `digital-item-table`

4) This works fine, but the new file details are added to the BOTTOM of the table, where I needed them added to the TOP of the table.

5) I've tried quite a few different things with jquery, but have not had any success. Not to mention, there is no associated jquery for adding the new row to the bottom so I think it must be related to the python itself (to which I'm a novice and new to this specific web application).

This is the associated python:

```
    def getCollectionItems(self):
        self.api_consumer = api_dfs.getConsumerAccount()
        request_url = api_dfs.getRequestUrl('client/collection/retrieve')   
        request_values = {'SessionToken': self.session_token, 'ClientToken': self.client_token}
        response_dict = self.api_consumer.request(request_url, request_values)
        response_dict = json.loads(response_dict)
        collection_data =  response_dict.get('Collection')  
        if collection_data:
            collection_items = collection_data.get('ChildPermissions')
        else:
            collection_items = [] 
        logging.info(response_dict)
        return collection_items
```

And this is the jquery I've tried to toy with but no success in adding the new row to the top of the table:

```
        add: function (e, data) {   
            $('.file-error-message').parent().remove(); 
            data.context = $("<div class='file-row-digital' ></div>").html('<div style="float:right;" >' + loader_element + '</div> Uploading...').appendTo('#uploadedFiles');
            $('#uploadedFiles').show();
            $('#digital-item-table tr:first').before($('.file-row-digital'));
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {          
            if (data.result.Status == 'success')            
            {
                data.context.html("<div class='new-row'>"+ data.result.LicenseCode + " " + data.result.Name + "</div>");
            }
            else
            {
                data.context.html("<div class='file-error-message' >" + data.result.ErrorMessage[0] + "</div>");
            }
        }
```

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately made this way too complicated; I just ended up using `reversed`, like so:

```
{% for item in collection_items reversed %}
```